# Selenium 2 StackOverflowError, JSONObject

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.24.1 and I get this error:

```
Caused an ERROR 
null 
java.lang.StackOverflowError 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:988) 
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272) 
at org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587) 
at org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990) 
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:272)
```

I am not sure what I am missing, and I have json-20080701.jar, and all the jar files came with selenium-java-2.24.1 and selenium-server-2.24.1.

even when use selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar only, I still get this error message.

any help please?

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you have an Object graph with cyclic dependencies.

Here's an example:

```
public class Parent{
    private List<Child> children;
}

public class Child{
    private Parent parent;
}
```

If you tried to serialize this to JSON, you would also get a StackOverflow unless your algorithm was aware of cyclic dependencies.

Because for every parent, a list of children would have to be created, each of which had a parent, each of which had a list of children and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was using Selenium 2.6 and everything was fine, why would this happen only when get to use Selenium 2.24.1? what Do you suggest for solution?

Comment: I don't know Selenium, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your project has org.json classes of other/older versions than the ones WebDriver needs on its classpath. And your json version doesn't work with WebDriver.

If you check your selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar, you will find org.json is included.

It means the project has 2 different versions of json jar on its classpath.

Welcome to JAR hell.

Solution:
Replace your json library with the one comes with selenium which locats in /Selenium-x.xx/lib/json-20080701.jar